# Trying to determine if the variance in my data is significant. Unsure whether to use chi squared test or difference of proportions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test

I have 11,497 NBA games sorted into 7 categories, based on whether the away team is in their *n*th game of a road trip, for values of *n* between 1 and 6. The 7th category is for values of *n* > 6.

To clarify what I mean by the nth game of a road trip, let's take an example.
Let's say Team A's 5 game schedule looks like this (@ indicates an away game, v. indicates home):

| Game 1 | Game 2 | Game 3 | Game 4 | Game 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| v. Team B | @Team C | @Team D | v. Team E | @Team F |

Game 1 would not be considered an away game for Team A, because they are home. Game 2 is the 1st game of a road trip, game 3 is the 2nd game of the road trip, Team A is home for game 4, and Game 5 is the 1st game of a new road trip. Game 5 is the start of a new road trip because it directly follows a home game.

My research question: **Does the winning percentage of NBA teams change for road trips of varying lengths?** (for an *n*-game road trip, the length of that road trip is *n*)

I have all the data, now all I need is the appropriate test to see if my findings are statistically significant.

My first thought was to use a chi squared test. The observed results are the number of games won over each of the 7 different values of *n* I am testing (The # of games won during the 1st game of a road trip, # of games won during the 2nd game of a road trip, etc..). For the expected results, I multiplied the sample size of each of the 7 categories by the away win percentage over all games, which yields the expected number of games won under the hypothesis that there is no change in win percentage as *n* changes. If the statistic of this test is large, then there probably is a statistically significant difference in the win percentage between away games with different values of *n*.

My hesitation with using this test is that it only tests the deviation of the data set as a whole from the expected result, but it doesn't compare the categories to each other. For example, maybe there is no statistical difference between the win percentage over the first 3 games of a road trip, but then something changes after that. Also, the test statistic is pretty low, but I don't know if that is because there is little statistical difference in win % between the categories, or rather because I am using the average win % over all away games to calculate the expected result, which is not independent of the win % for each individual category.

Ideally, I'd like to use something like a difference of proportions test, but I don't have 2 proportions, I have 7. Technically, I could compare 1 to 2, 2 to 3, 3 to 4, etc. using this method, but that seems clunky.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why have a category for $>6$ instead of analyzing the number of road games? Certainly $8$ is different from $7$.

Comment: @Dave The sample sizes get fairly small as n gets larger (the longer a road trip, the rarer it is).  There are 56 games for n = 7, 23 games for n = 8, 8 games for n = 9, and 1 game for n = 10. Perhaps I could have gotten away with making n = 7 its own category, but I thought that was pushing it.